# Is OData suitable for a big MVC5/WebAPI application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, odata, breeze, restier

I was working with the following stack MVC5 + WebAPI 2.2 + EF6 + AngularJS for my web application. Today, I tried to incorporate `OData` and `Angular BreezeJS` into my application and it worked fine for one of the entities.

Currently, I have around 45 tables which translate to 45 model classes.

In Web API, I could have just have 5-10 controllers to handle the CRUD operations for the 45 models using a switch statement based on the variables I pass like `entityName`, `operationName`.

But, in OData I need 45 controllers scaffold-ed by VS. Is there any way I can use the benefits of OData such as `querying/paging/patching` without having to create a controller for each model class ?

Answer (score 4):

Do you work with Entity Framework ? If so, you can try with RESTier. RESTier is **built upon Web API OData**, and it need only ONE controller to make all the basic CRUD (including queries) work.

You can learn more from the tutorial http://odata.github.io/RESTier/Getting-Started-Part-1/ and a sample with Northwind locates at https://github.com/OData/RESTier/tree/master/src/Microsoft.Restier.Samples.Northwind.

Comment: Looks cool. But since it's still at preview version, I would wait for its first major release.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this for an admin system for an ecommerce company. Probably about 20 tables and related api controllers, some of the tables have 10,000's record and all controllers have the odata bits enabled. It seems fine for me so far on Azure SQL and websites. I am using a controller per model/entity, why are you against doing that?

Comment: As of now, we are at 45 entities and as we expand we might add 15-20 more and I'm not comfortable in dealing with 60 controllers.  The other issue is that I need to have 60 different endpoints for using in Angular whereas in WebAPI I can do with 5-10